# commonly integrate a line of code at many places in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, devart

OK here my piece of code

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Userid=root;pwd=root;port=3306;host=localhost;database=test");
conn.Open();
```

Due to some issue with the new version of the devart connector i'm using i have  to add a line of code `OldCompatibility.BinaryAsString = true;`
everywhere in my code as shown below

```
OldCompatibility.BinaryAsString = true;
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnectio("User id=root;pwd=root;port=3306;host=localhost;database=test");
conn.Open();
```

But the problem is i have to make this change all over my application which have many pages with this piece of code.So is there any way to do this globally so that i dont have to make this change all over my application.
i'm using devart connector 6

Comment: For future, you would want to write one function for creating connection and centralizing the code :). For now : Do you have any base class or anything which is common to all pages ? You may want to put this line in a function which is called by every page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your connection is remotely similar each time; don't. Keep all your connection logic in one shared method, and use that instead of repeating the connection code everywhere.

```
public static MySqlConnection Connect() {
    OldCompatibility.BinaryAsString = true;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("User id=root;pwd=root;port=3306;host=localhost;database=test");
    conn.Open();

    return conn;
}
```

Comment: well in my application i'm not using any custom method like Connect so its not possible to do dat way coz if i do den i would have to change it everywhere

Comment: @Jay: That's the point. You'll pretty much have to change it everywhere regardless - you can use Find and Replace to help you with that, and that's about it. But if/when you have to change it again, you *won't* have to change it everywhere. Just use a method, stay [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself "Don't repeat yourself").

Answer (score 1):

MySqlConnection is your custom class if you put OldCompatibility.BinaryAsString = true in the constructor of MySqlConnection then it would work

Comment: I think MySQLConnection is a class for MYSQl driver for .Net.

Comment: Then make a new class MyCustomSQLConnection which wraps around MySQLConnection then it will serve your cause

Comment: 1) Which would again be required to change everywhere 2) Not sure if it's sealed or can be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

```
public class FactoryMethods
{
  public static MySqlConnection GetConfiguredConnection()
  {
    OldCompatibility.BinaryAsString = true;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnectio("User id=root;pwd=root;port=3306;host=localhost;database=test");
    conn.Open();
    return conn;
  }
}
```

And assuming the connection is IDispose-able

```
using (var myConn = FactoryMethods.GetConfiguredConnection())
{
  // Use your connection here
}
```

Comment: Though this is the right way to do it but again, he would need to make the change everywhere. If poster can live with that then I second this answer too.

Comment: @nonnb cant do it this way since that would require me to make changes all over my project

Comment: Doesn't DevArt have a web.config setting where you can globally tweak the compatability option? In future would recommend that you encapsulate and / or inject the creation of complex objects like SQL Connection strings to prevent this kind of maintenance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change all your code at once with find and replace using regular expressions:

1.- Hit Ctrl+H to open the “Find and Replace” window Enter your search, replace line breaks with “\n” (no quotes)

2.- Expand “Find options” and check “Use”, select “Regular Expressions” (this also activates the right arrow next to the “Find what” box. It lists a few commands/shortcuts).

For example:
Type this on find:

```
{MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection}
```

Then try this on replace:

```
OldCompatibility.BinaryAsString = true;\n\t\t\1 MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection
```

This will find all the code that matches the search and add an additional line infront of it. Notice the place holder {...} being replaced with \1

Answer (score 0):

You should ***really*** consider @minitech's suggestion on using a method, but if you really can't change the code anywhere, there are only really two options I can see;

- Extend MySQLConnection to a new class *using the same name* in another namespace, just changing the constructor to include your line. Then replace only the `using` line at the top of the file.
- If that can't be done, implement a wrapper class in the same manner.

Both these options may fail to work (#1 if the class is final for example, and #2 if the class is passed as a parameter to any functions), but unless you can at least do a global search/replace or implement @minitech's suggestion with a method, I can't see any other way.